# How to fix sprintf error

Tags: c, linux

The below code works just fine if I comment the sprintf line at the very bottom

```
int doStepOneAndTwo(){
FILE *fp, *source, *target, *fp1; 
   PROT prot;
   int i, j;
   int k, counter;
   int n_conf;
   int number_of_dir;
   int number_of_line;
   char sbuff[256];
   char str[256];
   char str1[256];
   int ch;
   const char *a[5];

   number_of_line = 140;
   number_of_dir = ceil( number_of_line /30) + 1;
   a[0] = "submit.sh";
   a[1] = FN_RUNPRM;   // run.prm
   a[2] = env.rename_rules; // name.txt
   a[3] = env.inpdb; // prot.pdb
   a[4] = STEP2_OUT; // step2_out.pdb

   for (i=1; i<=number_of_dir; i++)
    {

      sprintf(str,"_%d", i);
      mkdir(str,"0755"); // Create temporary directories

      for (j=0;j<5;j++)
      {
          sprintf(str,"%s", a[j]);
          source = fopen(str, "r");
          if( source == NULL ) 
            {
                printf("Error in doStepOneAndTwo, can't open file source \n");
                return USERERR;
            }
          sprintf(str,"_%d/%s", i, a[j]);
          target = fopen(str, "w");
          if( target == NULL ) 
            {
                fclose(source);
                printf("Error in doStepOneAndTwo, can't open file target %s \n",str);
                return USERERR;
            }


          while( (ch = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
              fputc(ch, target);
          }

          //if(k!=1){printf("foo");}else{printf("bar \n");}
          //k++;

      }

    }
    fclose(source);
    fclose(target);

for (k=1; k<2; k++)
    {
        printf("Yes %d \n",k);

        sprintf(str1,"_%d/run.prm",k); // If I comment this line everything works just fine 
        //chdir("_1");
        fp1=fopen(FN_RUNPRM, "r");
    }

return 0;

}
```

The error I get is "Error in doStepOneAndTwo, can't open file target _1/submit.sh" .  Basically, the target file is NULL.  I'm new to c and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you running this in the same directory as `submit.sh`? If not, then you need to specify the full path to the `submit.sh` file.

Comment: Are you expecting this file to exist, or do you intend to create it? fopen will create a file if it dne, but not a directory.

Comment: The submit.sh exist in one directory and I'm copying it to another directory .  Everything runs if I comment the sprintf line in the last for loop.  What I don't understand is that why the first loop is affected by the last loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it very difficult to believe that commenting out the `sprintf()` makes the program work for you.  Doing so does not make it work for me.

The main problem appears to be in your `mkdir()` call.  The file mode passed to that syscall is supposed to be an integer (specifically a `mode_t`) mode, but you are passing a pointer, converted to an integer.  This doesn't mean at all what you intend.  In my particular case, the resulting mode of the directory did not afford the owner write permission, resulting in exactly the error message you described.

This alternative `mkdir()` call does make your program work for me, regardless of whether the `sprintf()` at the end is quoted:

```
mkdir(str, 0755);
```

Note that the *unquoted* `0755` is an *octal* (base 8) literal, on account of starting with the digit `0` and not being a hexadecimal literal.  It would be more conventional to write it like this, though:

```
mkdir(str, S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | SIXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
```

You might need to include one or more of `sys/types.h`, `sys/stat.h`, and `fcntl.h` to get definitions for the mode macros.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, unquoting 0755 in mkdir().